# Autloading classes from Symfony Task

Tags: php, symfony1, command-line-interface, autoloader

I'm working with a Symfony 1.1 code-base and attempting to write a plugin containing a task that will automate some processes.

Currently I'm finding that inside the Task, Symfony does not completely bootstrap class autoloading.  It seems to register the `sfCoreAutoload` class but I'm unable to autoload other classes from the same plugin, or from any other plugins.

Directory structure resembles:

```
/project
  /plugin
    /myPlugin
      /lib
        /class
          myClass.class.php
        /task
          myTask.class.php
```

The Task loads fine but in this setup is unable to autoload `myClass`.  Usually I would just `require` the file, but `myClass` depends on another plugin being available.

It seems confusing that the Symfony CLI wouldn't register autoloading for the rest of the application you're currently running, similar to how it would for a web app.

Comment: Have you had a look in: http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_1/19-Mastering-Symfony-s-Configuration-Files#chapter_19_extending_the_autoloading_feature ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've run into one of several annoying aspects of Symfony tasks.

If you can put whatever you're doing in `execute` instead of `configure`, you should be alright. I believe every task's `configure` method is called on every task execution, so you don't want anything heavy in there anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Currently solved the problem by manually setting up autoloaders in `execute`.

Comment: You should be able to access `myClass` in `execute`. If you can't, something else funky is going on.

Comment: You are absolutely correct! I generated a fresh Symfony 1.1 sandbox and was able to autoload other classes from the same plugin. I think the old code-base has been hacked at a bit.